# Is it Blogger or LibreOffice who is adding so many useless SPAN tags into my text, and why?

Tags: blogger, html

I write in LibreOffice Writer, then I copy and paste into Blogger text editor (Compose button). Why in the world a simple and unformatted text such as

```
Helmut Sick (Tukani: entre os animais e os índios do Brasil Central)
```

become a mess such as

```
<span style="font-style: normal;"><span style="font-weight: normal;"><span style="background: #ffffff;">
Helmut Sick (Tukani: </span></span></span><span style="font-style: normal;"><span style="font-weight: normal;"><span style="background: #ffffff;">e</span></span></span><span style="font-style: normal;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">ntre
os </span></span><span style="font-style: normal;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">a</span></span><span style="font-style: normal;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">nimais
e os </span></span><span style="font-style: normal;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">í</span></span><span style="font-style: normal;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">ndios
do Brasil </span></span><span style="font-style: normal;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">C</span></span><span style="font-style: normal;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">entral</span></span><span style="font-style: normal;"><span style="font-weight: normal;"><span style="background: #ffffff;">)</span></span></span>
```

As you can see, the tags

```
<span style="font-style: normal;"><span style="font-weight: normal;"><span style="background: #ffffff;">
```

keep repeating, sometimes for a single character. In the whole page, sometimes it's only one of these tags, sometimes two, and now all three, and for no obvious reason. Is there a way to have only the necessary tags when I paste a text into Blogger editor?

Answer (score 0):

It is a Blogger issue. I can fix one span/br and then it seems to cascade through the paragraphs every time I save. Under post Options select Line Breaks by the enter and not the br also highlight the whole text and press Tx to remove formatting that will space out the paragraphs which you can then even up by either backspacing or deleting.

Comment: I don't want to remove formatting, because my text has lots of italics, bold and other formatting. I guess I'll look for other html generator, and then paste the code into the HTML window of Blogger. Also, my problem is not only with the `br` tag, since the `span` tag is appearing multiple times inside each paragraph.